# firebase hosting: rewrite url resulting static file url path changes

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-hosting

I was trying to have my ionic single page application to have a url navigation, everything will work fine if I do
`project-id.com/#/register/id`.
If I enter this url I will be in the correct page and url changes to
`project-id.com/register/id` (I think this is because ionic doing locationStrategy:'path')

however if I want to do no # with just
`project-id.com/register/id`

It will try to get my static assets with project-id.com/register/blah
i.e  instead of getting
`project-id.com/cordova.js`, it will do
`project-id.com/register/cordova.js`.

Now if I do 
`project-id.com/register/somemore/id`
it will go fetch
`project-id.com/register/somemore/cordova.js`

I've tried many rewrites, but none of it worked,
my current one is the default rewrite. This will make every static assets become index.html

```js
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a reproducible version of the bug? The rewrite sample you provide should rewrite any URL that isn't an exact match for a deployed file to `index.html`.

Comment: Do you have <base href="/"> in index.html?

Answer (score 1):

it turns out I need to give absolute path like /assets/js/something.js instead of assets/js/somthing.js

Comment: I had /src/assets/img/my-img.png, which was corrected by changing to /assets/img/my-img.png per your suggestion - thank you!